# issue understanding backtracking (recursion) in java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

i'm trying to understand a solution for the leetcode problem #22 where we generate parentheses recursively and I'm stuck on where the function returns to after we find the first combination of parentheses

the question asks you to create all possible valid (open and close correctly) combinations of n-parentheses pairs. so for n=2 the answer is a list being = [ "()()", "(())" ]

this is the code solution (credits: nick white):

```
class Solution {
    
    // first
    public List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {
        List<String> output_arr = new ArrayList();
        backtrack(output_arr, "", 0, 0, n);
        return output_arr;
    }
    
    // backtracking recursive method
    public void backtrack (List<String> output_arr, String current_string, int open, int closed, int max){
        // base case
        if (current_string.length() == max*2){
            output_arr.add(current_string);
            return;
        }
        // recursive
        if (open < max) backtrack(output_arr, current_string + "(", open+1, closed, max);
        if (closed < open) backtrack(output_arr, current_string + ")", open, closed+1, max);
    }  
}
```

this is my interpretation of the recursive calls for an example case of n=2, but I'm not sure this is correct:

```
/*
example - n = 2

backtrack (output_arr, "", 0, 0, 2)

into method 2

if (cs.length == 4) add to output arr & return
if (open < 2) backtrack (output_arr, "(", 1, 0, 2 );     # A
if (closed < open) backtrack 

into # A - backtrack (output_arr, "(", 1, 0, 2 );

if (cs.length == 4) add, return
if (open < 2) backtrack (output_arr, "((", 2, 0, 2 );    # B
if (closed < open)   - do we come here after we fail to find anything in # H??? 

    RETURNED HERE FROM # D - open = 1, closed = 0. closed < open
    backtrack ( output_arr, "()", 1, 1, 2 )   # E 
    
    into # E 
    
    if (cs.length)
    if (open <2)  backtrack (output_arr, "()(", 2, 1, 2)   # F
    if (closed < open) 
        after into # G, we return HERE! lets call this #H closed is not less than open (1 == 1) now where do we go to?
    
    into # F
    
    if (cs.length)
    if (open <2)
    if (closed < open)  backtrack (output_arr, "()()", 2, 2, 2)  # G
    
    int # G
    
    if (cs.length)
        output arr . add [ "(())", "()()" ] 
        return  - WHERE TO ??

into # B

if (cs.length == 4) add, return
if (open <2)
if (closed < open)  backtrack (out_arr, "(()", 2, 1, 2)   # C

into # C

if ( cs.length == 4) add, return
if (open < 2)
if (closed < open) backtrack (out_arr, "(())", 2, 2, 2)    # D

into # D

if ( cs.length == 4) add, return: 
    output arr ["(())"]
    return  -- WHERE DO WE RETURN TO?

*/
```

Comment: I think, you are going in right direction, let me add few points which may help you, after two calls for close you get the first result, which is added and returned immediately, now you have control back after close but there is nothing after it so it will return to previous close, where same will happen and it returns from there as well, now your control reaches back to open if (here you went into close first time).

Comment: Now, the second open has completed and corresponding close also executed so it will return and you will reach after first open call, which has waiting close call with params (1,0, '(' ) and so on...